# Why Convolution function in MXnet have a kernel parameter

Tags: python, mxnet

I am new of mxnet, in the official doc, the generation of a convolution layer could be

```
conv = nd.Convolution(data=data, weight=W, bias=b, kernel=(3,3), num_filter=10)
```

But it is required that the `weight` parameter needs to take a 4-D tensor

```
W = [weight_num, stride, kernel_height, kernel_width]
```

So why we still need to set a `kernel` parameter in `Convolution` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kernel` parameter sets up the kernel size, which can be either:

- (width,) - for 1D convolution
- (height, width) - for 2D convolution
- (depth, height, width) - for 3D convolution

It only defines shapes.

The `weight` and `bias` parameters contain actual parameters that are going to be trained. The actual values are going to be here.

While you could probably figure out `kernel` (shapes) by provided `weight`, it is more defensive to ask to provide `kernel` shape explicitly instead of trying figuring it out based on parameters passed to `weight`.

Here is an example of 2D convolution:

```
# shape is batch_size x channels x height x width
x = mx.nd.random.uniform(shape=(100, 1, 9, 9))
# kernel is just 3 x 3, 
# weight is num_filter x channels x kernel_height x kernel_width
# bias is num_filter
mx.nd.Convolution(data=x, 
                  kernel=(3, 3), 
                  num_filter=5, 
                  weight=mx.nd.random.uniform(shape=(5, 1, 3, 3)), 
                  bias=mx.nd.random.uniform(shape=(5,)))
```

The documentation explaining various shapes of parameters in case of 1D, 2D or 3D convolutions is quite good: https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/ndarray/ndarray.html#mxnet.ndarray.Convolution